# Visual Basic, insert a function to one column, based on the range of another

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro to clean up exported data from one application to upload it into another. I'm new to vba, but not programming, relatively.

I was hoping to get this out of it:

1. Set the range equal to the last row of column B
2. Insert the Formula2 = "=B1&""-""&C1" into column AS, but only down to the range of column B's last cell

I found a post suggesting this to set the last row and use it for range, but i'm unsure how to tie it into the rest of my script

```
myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).Row
```

This code works, but the current range spits it out against the entireity of the AS column, and adds a "-" to everything after columns B and C are empty.

```
Worksheets("export-data").Range("AS:AS").Formula2 = "=B1&""-""&C1"

Worksheets("export-data").Range("AS:AS").Copy Worksheets("Acumatica").Range("G:G")
```

I'm hoping to just insert that Formula in a range of AS equal to populated cells in column B

Comment: `x1Up` will not work.  It should be `xlUp` that is a lowercase `L` not the number `1`.

Comment: and then you want to use that variable.  You are assigning it to the full column.  Instead limit the range: `Worksheets("export-data").Range("AS1:AS" & myLastRow )`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, when I copy over the result, i get a reference error. Is there a way to copy the output of the formula in the cell, rather than the formula?

Comment: `Worksheets("Acumatica").Range("G1:G" & myLastRow).Value = Worksheets("export-data").Range("AS1:AS" & myLastRow) .value`

Comment: Scott, you're my hero. The only other thing I'd like to do with this sheet is insert a value based on what data is present in another column.

basically:

cost code description of toolwatch needs to translate to the cost code number
if present in column k of export-data, fill in column F of acumatica with a corresponding code

01-5213 = Field Office Setup & Supplies
01-6520 = Material Handling Equipment
01-5214 = Temporary Storage Trailer